# What ESP8266 module is this?

Tags: esp8266

I found an old box with 4 ESP8266 module.  I initially thought they were ESP8266 -05, but this chip only has 4 pins (with a separate ground) instead of 5 pins (with a separate ground).  This is pretty old, so I'm wondering if it was a difference chipset before they upgraded it?

[image]

If anyone could give me any information (specifically schematics) for this thing, that'd be great.

Thanks!

Comment: @replete Thanks for your comment. I edited the question, I'm just re-learning everything and didn't want to ruin anything by testing.  I think I found that it's just a variant of the -05, but with out the reset pin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have several of these.  They are an ESP-05 without the reset pin.

From the top the pins are Gnd, RXD, TXD, Vcc (3.3V).

[image: Pinout graphic, from the [ESP8266 Wiki](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?cache=&w=434&h=325&tok=c0ee97&media=05-4-04.jpg)]

Comment: Thank you Dean!  A quick follow-up question.  Once connected to vcc and gnd, does this piece blink a single red LED.  If so, have you been able to do anything with it using an arduino? and which version?

Comment: When powered up the red led blinks once.  The board uses the standard serial command set for the stock ESP firmware.  I have not used these modules with Arduino but I don't think you will have any issues (at least with the arduino library that uses the ESP boards as a serial device). I have no idea whether you can reprogram the ESP8266 using the ESP Arduino environment.

Comment: Thank you Dean! I noticed the LED blink when powered on, though I'm wondering, Should this chip be sending a signal with power only?  I have limited experience with the ESP-01 and I know once it's powered up, it transmits an SSID.  Do I need to program this chip just to transmit?

Comment: General getting started with the ESP-05 and Arduino: http://datafirmwarejuk.blogspot.com/2016/08/esp-05-mini-esp8266-wifi-module.html